# Android launcher that creates and deletes apps by itself

Tags: android, launcher

I'm pretty new to Android, I do know some Java though.

I want to make a launcher that can create apps and delete them based on some conditions (on the time of day, for example).  So in the morning, it shows the app on screen, and at night, it deletes it.

If the app files are already there, is this possible?
How would I do this, please include some example code
Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by create and delete apps? do actually want to remove them from the system? or just from the launcher screen?

Comment: Just remove them from the launcher screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well provided that you only want to toggle display of applications, start with the source code from the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191602/how-to-re-build-the-default-launcher-application?rq=1).  That should get you started - as for time of day, that's pretty trivial to get from the system.  If you want to include widgets, though, like the answer I pointed you to mentions, that doesn't seem to beexposed with the current API (although [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746173/adding-widgets-to-a-launcher-page-without-bindappwidgetid) seems to indicate that its possible, I just haven't tried it).

Good luck!