# Android - How to change launcher theme (device theme) programmatically

Tags: android, android-theme

***Briefly;***

*I'm working on a 'Device Production Test' project. We are developing system applications to test whether the API provided by the manifacturer is stable or not.*

I need to **set Android launcher application theme programmatically** and check system level warnings and errors during this process.
I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191602/how-to-re-build-the-default-launcher-application) in SO but the source code link is broken.

How can I change Android theme programmatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use  this code in manifest file   If you really want to launch the activity which I write.

```
<activity  
      android:name=".LaunchedActivityName"  
      android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >  
      <intent-filter>  
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>  
      </intent-filter>  
 </activity>
```

Comment: He didn't ask for App launching, but device launching process.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// set your custom theme here before setting layout
super.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

Comment: Ok. To make more clear, your answer is valid for your own application. I'm asking how to set Android Device theme, not application theme. This is not an answer to my question.

Comment: You should update your answer instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Do you want change Android Device theme in Android Device..Ok